# Image GET request interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTTP request interceptor:

```
var app = angular.module('mobApp.services');
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      var utils = $injector.get('Utils'),
      userDetails = utils.getCurrentUserDetails();
      config.headers.Authorization = "Token 12309123019238";
      if(userDetails) {
        config.headers['X-AccessKey'] = userDetails.apiKey;
        config.headers['X-UserId'] =  userDetails.id;
      }
      return config;
    }
  }

});

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
}]);
```

It add `X-` header to all GET/POST request except to a image GET request. why?

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you want to intercept the request from a
`<img ng-src="someurl"/>` tag

In this case you need to replace `ng-src="someurl"` with `http-src="someurl"`

Otherwise these will not be fetched with `$http` and thus not pass your interceptor

to make this work you need a custom directive:

```
app.directive('httpSrc', [
        '$http', function ($http) {
            var directive = {
                link: link,
                restrict: 'A'
            };
            return directive;

            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                var requestConfig = {
                    method: 'Get',
                    url: attrs.httpSrc,
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                    cache: 'true'
                };

                $http(requestConfig)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        var arr = new Uint8Array(data);

                        var raw = '';
                        var i, j, subArray, chunk = 5000;
                        for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
                            subArray = arr.subarray(i, i + chunk);
                            raw += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, subArray);
                        }

                        var b64 = btoa(raw);

                        attrs.$set('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64);
                    });
            }

        }
    ]);
```